# Iterate Minimize on a list of functions

Tags: mathematical-optimization, map

I have a function $f$ defined on $[-1,1]$.
For a minimal example, it suffices to define

```
f[z_]:=z^2 - 1
```

I need to find a list of points such that $f(z_0)= f(z_1)$, points whose image "lies at the same height". 
I proceeded by finding the minimum via

```
  min = First@Minimize[f[z], {z}]
```

which occurs for $z$ equal to

```
argmin = Values@Last@Minimize[f[z], {z}]
```

I further created a list with

```
  rang = Subdivide[a, 0,10]
```

spanning the range from the minimum to the a predefined value.

Now I would like to find, for each element of this list, points such that $f(z_0)=f(z_1) = rang_j$, for each element of the list.

I could not find any better plan than to define a list of functions $fun_j = (f(z)+rang_j)^2$. By shifting the original function and squaring I am certain that the functions $fun_j$, one for each element in the list $rang$ are positive everywhere except the roots.

I wanted then to iterate over the list of functions a constrained minimization via the commands (the argument $f_j$ being just used to clarify my question, I understand the sintax will be different actually that is exactly what the question is about):

```
   Minimize[{f_j, z > argmin}, {z}]
   Minimize[{f_j, z > argmin}, {z}]
```

that is, running two minimisations one to the left and one to the right of the ${arg\,min}$. I know on mathematical grounds two unique solutions exists.

I create my list of functions as

```
 f1[z_,c_]:=f[z]+c
```

and then using

```
 f1[z,rang]
```

but I struggle with iterating Minimize, any suggestion would be helpful.

Trying

```
  Minimize[{f1[ z, rang], z > b}, z]
```

yields an error message, as the function argument of Minimize is expected to be a scalar function.
I would also love to hear about better methods altoghether, in general and in reference to Mathematica.
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 Module[{f0},
  f0 = func /. z -> z0;
  pts = {z, func} /.
     NSolve[{func == f0, -1 <= z <= 1}, z, Reals] // Normal;
  Column[{
    Row[{TraditionalForm[f[Subscript[z, 0]]], " = ", f0}],
    Row[{"z values = ", NumberForm[Or @@ (First /@ pts), {5, 3}]}],
    Plot[func, {z, -1, 1},
     Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
     FrameLabel -> {z, func},
     Epilog -> {Green, Dashed, Line[pts], Red,
       AbsolutePointSize[4], (Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ pts)},
     ImageSize -> Medium]}]],
 {{func, z^2 - 1, "function"}, {z^2 - 1 -> TraditionalForm[z^2 - 1],
   z (z^2 - 9/16) -> TraditionalForm[z (z^2 - 9/16)],
   Sin[2 Pi z] -> TraditionalForm[Sin[2 Pi z]]},
  ControlType -> RadioButtonBar},
 {{z0, 0, TraditionalForm[Subscript[z, 0]]}, -1, 1, 0.005, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** `pts` was removed from the list of local variables in the `Module` which moved it into the `Global` name space.

```
Dynamic[First /@ pts]
```

[image]

```
Dynamic[Integrate[z^2 - 1, {z, pts[[1, 1]], pts[[2, 1]]}]]
```

[image]

Or with static values

```
Integrate[z^2 - 1, {z, pts[[1, 1]], pts[[2, 1]]}]

(* -0.953531 *)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this. extremely instructive. It will take me some time to decipher it, but I appreciate your help. I need to use the pairs of values as upper and lower integration limits of a list of integrals, so I need to understand how to get them out of your code in a form suitable to be used in Integrate. The Manipulate feature is stunning though.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function over the range `{-1,1}`

```
f[z_] := Sin[2π z]
Plot[f[z], {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

A function to find possible `z1` given a `z0`, uses `Reduce` to find all solutions.

```
findZ1[z0_] := Reduce[{f[x] == f[z0], x != z0, -1 <= x <= 1}, {x}]
```

Note the `x!=z0` term in there. It doesn't seem to work, I left it in there to show I tried it.

Pick a `z0`

```
res= findZ1[.2]

(* x == -0.8 || x == -0.7 || x == 0.2 || x == 0.3 *)
```

Convert to rules

```
{ToRules[res]} // Flatten
(* {x -> -0.8, x -> -0.7, x -> 0.2, x -> 0.3} *)
```

you'll need to remove the `z1` that matches the orginal `z0`.

**EDIT**

For a simple function that is everywhere convex and the minimum lies in the interval `{-1,1}`...

```
f[z_] := (z^2) - 1
```

Subdivide the interval. It's not clear to me what you are doing in your question, so just subdivide it from 0 to 1. Drop the first point, which is at the minimum.

```
pts = Subdivide[0, 1, 5]//Rest
(* {1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1} *)

findZ1[z0_] := First@Values@ToRules@Reduce[{f[x] == f[z0], x != z0, -1 <= x <= 1}, {x}]

Map[findZ1, pts]
(* {-(1/5), -(2/5), -(3/5), -(4/5), -1} *)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this. I need to iterate your function findZ1: the function I am considering is such that your findZ1 it will return 2 values, and I want to use them as upper and lower integration limits in the next stage of the code. How can I iterate findZ1, over different values? If I define a list ran = {0.8,0.6,0.4.0.2}, I was hoping to be able to get pairs of values like with  Apply[findZ1, ran], but it is not the case.

Comment: OK, if we can guarantee the shape is convex upward in the interval...see my edit. We use `Map` instead of `Apply`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works and I have learnt a few things.